# Get JSON data from external form in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have an external web form which posts data to my controller URL. The data is sent in a JSON string.

What I need to do is get the individual values in the JSON string and add them to my database. However I'm having some trouble getting the posted values and decoding them.

Here is the code which I tried - any help would be much appreciated Thanks.

```
public function index() { 
    $this->load->view('lead');
    $form_data = array(
    'firstname' => json_decode($this->input->post('first_name')),
    'lastname' =>json_decode($this->input->post('last_name')),
    'number' =>json_decode($this->input->post('phone_number')),
    'email' =>json_decode($this->input->post('email')),
    'suburb' =>json_decode($this->input->post('suburb')),
    'state' =>json_decode($this->input->post('state')),
    'enquiry' =>json_decode($this->input->post('enquiry'))
);

// run insert model to write data to db

if ($this->AddLeadModel->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db { //Do something if successful }
```

Comment: Kindly check the JSON string format. Check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not json_decode the individual form fields.
You have to json_decode the incoming field with the json instead,
then use the array data to populate the form again.

In easy words: You from fields were stuffed into an array on JS side, then json_encoded for transfer to the server. Now you need to expand the json to get the array back.

```
// decode the incomning json 
// you get an array
$json_array = json_decode($this->input->post('the_form_field_name_of_your_json'));

// now assign the array data to the form
$form_data = array(
    'firstname' => $json_array['first_name'],
    ...
    ...
);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, needed some slights modifications but worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input_data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Will explain with an example (THIS WORKS):**

```
// Assuming the values you are getting via POST

$first_name = '{"first_name" : "Parag"}';
$last_name = '{"last_name" : "Tyagi"}';
$phone_number = '{"phone_number" : "9999999999"}';

$form_data['firstname'] = json_decode($first_name, TRUE)['first_name'];
$form_data['lastname'] = json_decode($last_name, TRUE)['last_name'];
$form_data['number'] = json_decode($phone_number, TRUE)['phone_number'];

print_r($form_data);
```

**DEMO:**

http://3v4l.org/dmIrr

**Now check below (THIS WON'T WORK):**

```
// Assuming the values you are getting via POST

$first_name = "{'first_name' : 'Parag'}";
$last_name = "{'last_name' : 'Tyagi'}";
$phone_number = "{'phone_number' : '9999999999'}";

$form_data['firstname'] = json_decode($first_name, TRUE)['first_name'];
$form_data['lastname'] = json_decode($last_name, TRUE)['last_name'];
$form_data['number'] = json_decode($phone_number, TRUE)['phone_number'];

print_r($form_data);
```

**DEMO:**

http://3v4l.org/MeJoU

**Explanation:**

If you pass the JSON in your post to `json_decode`, it will fail. Valid JSON strings have **quoted keys**. Hence check your case and see in what format are you getting the JSON (via POST).

Comment: The (subtle) difference between the two is the use of double quotes (`"`) and single quotes (`'`) in the JSON strings.

Comment: Yes exactly. That might be one of the reason the OP is not getting its decoded value.

Comment: This might work, but i find it better to serialize the form to json and transfer that object, instead of transfering each form field as json. Keywords: "jquery post form serialized" - `var form_data = $("#form").serialize();` - http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/.